# MySQL select duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am selecting the columns State and Zip3 twice in my select statement, stating exactly what I want to see. When I do it in native MySQL I get the right result:

```
SELECT State,Zip3, FirstName, LastName, State, Zip3 
FROM Person
WHERE State >= 'A'
ORDER BY State, Zip3
LIMIT 10;

+-------+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
| State | Zip3 | FirstName | LastName    | State | Zip3 |
+-------+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
| AB    | T7X  | Adalei    | Starreveld  | AB    | T7X  |
| AK    | 998  | Linda     | Rosenthal   | AK    | 998  |
| AL    | 361  | Benjamin  | Sung        | AL    | 361  |
| AL    | 362  | Lawrence  | Kallus      | AL    | 362  |
| AZ    | 857  | Rose      | Springfield | AZ    | 857  |
| CA    | 941  | Maura     | Cronin      | CA    | 941  |
| CA    | 941  | Dov       | Grunschlag  | CA    | 941  |
| CA    | 943  | Ruth      | Hodos       | CA    | 943  |
| CT    | 055  | Andrew    | Salvo       | CT    | 055  |
| CT    | 064  | DEBORAH   | GRASER      | CT    | 064  |
+-------+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
```

When I do it in Cold Fusion I get a wrong result:

```
<cfquery name = "stest" datasource = "Moxart">
select State,Zip3, FirstName,LastName,State,Zip3 from Person
where State >= 'A'
order by State,Zip3
</cfquery>
<cfset j = 0>
<table>
<cfoutput query = "stest">
<tr>
<cfloop index = "col" list = "#columnlist#">
<cfset j = j + 1>
<cfset colname[j] = #stest[col][currentrow]#>
<td>   #colname[j]# </td>
</cfloop><br/>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>


Adalei      Starreveld      AB      AB      T7X     T7X  
Linda       Rosenthal       AK      AK      998     998 
Benjamin    Sung            AL      AL      361     361
Lawrence    Kallas          AL      AL      362     362
Rose        Springfield     AZ      AZ      857     857
Maura       Cronin          CA      CA      941     941
Dov         Grunschlag      CA      CA      941     941
Ruth        Hodos           CA      CA      943     943
Andrew      Salvo           CT      CT      055     055
DEBORAH     GRASER          CT      CT      064     064
```

How can I get the correct result out of ColdFusion. I am using ColdFusion 8 and Firefox.

Comment: First of all, MySQL doesn't allow these kind of duplicate columns in a table structure, do they?

Comment: @PraveenKumar There are no duplicate columns in the table structure. What is shown here is the result of a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 6):

Try giving the columns an alias

```
select 
  State,
  Zip3, 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  State AS State_2,
  Zip3 as Zip3_2 
from 
  Person
where 
  State >= 'A'
order by 
  State,
  Zip3
```

Comment: Yep, you need an alias so all query column names are unique. Otherwise CF will not know which column you want when you use #Zip3#

Comment: Also `#columnlist#` returns the column names in alphabetical order. To obtain the original order, use `getMetaData(query)`. It returns an array of structures containing column properties. Alternately, you can use the undocumented `yourQueryName.getColumnList()` method. It returns a string array of column names (only).

Comment: Hi Guys, I did try the alias thing, didn't work.  But did solve the problem, which was the variable columnlist over which I am looping.  Columnlist is always in alphabetic order.  To retain the requested order I used <cfset trulist = #ArrayToList(stest.getColumnList())#>, and then looped over trulist.  This worked perfectly.  Hard as it may be to imagine, there are sometimes good reasons to request a field twice.

Answer (score 2):

> I did try the alias thing, didn't work. But did solve the problem,
>   which was the variable columnlist over which I am looping.

**Maintaining column Order**

Well you did not actually describe what was wrong with the output in your original question ;) However, as I mentioned in the comments, `columnList` always uses alphabetical order. To obtain the original order either

1. Use `getMetaData(query)`. It returns an array of structures containing the query column properties, including `name`.
2. Alternately, you could use the *undocumented* `query.getColumnList()` method instead. It returns an array of column names (only).

Then simply use a `cfloop array`. No need to convert to a list, unless you are using MX7 or earlier (which did not support array loops).

```
    <!--- using getMetaData --->
    <cfset colProps = getMetaData(someQuery) />
    <cfoutput query="someQuery">
        <cfloop array="#colProps#" index="col">
            #someQuery[ col.Name ][ currentRow ]# |
        </cfloop>
        <br />
    </cfoutput>

    <!--- using undocumented getColumnList() --->
    <cfset colNames = someQuery.getColumnList() />
    <cfoutput query="someQuery">
        <cfloop array="#colNames#" index="col">
            #someQuery[ col ][ currentRow ]# |
        </cfloop>
        <br />
    </cfoutput>
```

---

> there are sometimes good reasons to request a field twice

**Unique Query Column Names**

Honestly, I cannot think of many good reasons to return the *same* column multiple times. As Dan pointed out, you could easily output it multiple times. So I am curious as to your use case.

Returning the *same column name* multiple times in the result is problematic because it is ambiguous. So CF has no idea which column you want when you reference it. In your particular case it does not matter because the values are the same in both. But consider this example where the data values are different, but the same column name is assigned to both:

```
<cfquery name="someQuery" datasource="someDSN">
    SELECT  1 AS Zip3, 2 AS Zip3 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  8 AS Zip3, 16 AS Zip3 
</cfquery>
```

If you were to output `#zip3#`, what should the correct result be? If you actually dump the query the results are:

```
  RESULTSET query 
  Row  | ZIP3 | ZIP3 
  1    | 1    | 1  
  2    | 8    | 8
```

Because CF has no idea which values to use for "Zip3", it apparently just picks the first column it finds to resolve the ambiguity. The values in the second "Zip3" column are simply discarded. That is why you should always use an alias to ensure query column names are unique.

Of course that is assuming it even works in other versions. I vaguely remember something about some versions throwing an error when duplicate column names are encountered. But as it is not something I normally do, I would have to run tests to verify it.

Comment: You are right, I had figured out the problem was the alphabetized columnlist.  Since I refer only to  queryname[col][currentrow] and not the column names it is unambiguous.  Re selecting the same field twice, it is in a user service where they can select what columns they want to see on their report, and how to sort them.  If they select a column both to see and to order by, then it will turn up twice.  They might not have intented that result, but I didn't want to give them an error for that. I have very occasionally -once every 10 years? - needed a report with a repeated column.

Comment: I recently made a report like that and I saw no need to select a column twice just because the user wanted to sort by it.  On the other hand, I had the form set up so that the user could only sort by fields that they were going to see.  If you want to know how to do this, ask another question because it really is a different topic.

Comment: @BettyMock - Not quite. The code *does* refer to the column name ie `queryName[columnName][currentRow]`. But that is not where the problem lies. The ambiguity issue occurs long before that. When CF *creates* the query object, from the database results, it encounters two columns of values both claiming to be `zip3`. It can only pick one, so it uses the first one ie `1,8` and discards the second one ie `2,16`. Again, it is not an issue in this specific case. But would definitely be a problem in others. (cont'd)

Comment: Re: *to see and order by* I agree with Dan. "Sorting" and "View" columns are two distinct things. From what you have described, there is no reason to include it twice. You could easily prevent that by restructuring the form.

Comment: Of course there is no need to select the column twice in order to sort on it. That is not how it comes up.  @Leigh I much appreciate the explanation of where the ambiguity lies.  I'm new to this technology and want to understand as well as I can. Given what the form is, and what the output may be, restructuring does not seem possible; but I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest selecting once, displaying twice.  Something like this:

```
<cfscript>
Headers = "State,Zip Code,First Name,Last Name,State,Zip Code";
Fields = "state,zip3,FirstName,LastName,State,Zip3";
</cfscript>

<cfquery name = "stest" datasource = "Moxart">
select State, Zip3, FirstName, LastName
from Person
where State >= 'A'
order by State,Zip3
</cfquery>

<table>
<tr>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index = "thisHeader" List = "#Headers>
<th>#thisHeader#</th>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
</tr>
<cfoutput query = "stest">
<tr>
<cfloop list = "#fields#" index = "thisField">
<td>#stest[thisField][currentrow]#</td>
</cfloop>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Note that I didn't actually test this code.  There may be a syntax error or two but the logic is fine.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you are calling it twice but here's how I would do it:

```
SELECT state, first_name, last_name zip FROM person WHERE state >= 'a' ORDER BY state, zip
```

If truly zip shows up twice in the table and you want to make sure they match

```
SELECT state, first_name, last_name zip FROM person WHERE state >= 'a' AND zip = zip ORDER BY state, zip
```

Comment: Not sure what you were after, but that query will not do what you are thinking. Using `WHERE zip = zip` means find all records where the zip value *equals itself*. It will always be true (except for `null` values)